# video.js fallback is not working

Tags: html, flash, firefox, video, video.js

**This is my code**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="javascripts/video.js-stable/dist/video-js/video.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javascripts/video.js-stable/dist/video-js/video-js.css" />

    <script>
   videojs.options.flash.swf ="http://localhost/site/public/javascripts/video.js-stable/dist/video-js/video-js.swf";   
   </script>
    <title>video</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
controls="" preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
poster=""
data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
         <source src="http://localhost/site/public/videos/ogg.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>    

 </video>
  </body>
 </html>
```

when i play video in firefox 3 then firefox crashed and when i use firefox 11 then it play fine...i read somewhere that firefox is not suported mp4 videos in html5.
If mp4 is not supported by firefox in html5,that means my code is using flash,because video is playing fine in firefox 11,or how can i check my code is using flash as fallback.
one more thing when i try to play 3gp video then it show error in all modern browser.
error:**Sorry no compatible source and playback technology is found.**
what is real problem ?? please help. thanks in advcance!!

Answer (score 0):

- For more information about Firefox MP4 support, visit this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats).
- Specify multiple alternative media resources for compatibility using `source`:

  ```
  <video ...>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    ...
  </video>
  ```
- Place `object` with flash inside `video` to provide fallback:

  ```
  <video ...>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    ...
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash_player.swf" ...>
      <param name="movie" value="flash_player.swf">
      <param name="flashvars" value="flash-variables">
      ...
    </object>
  </video>
  ```
- `.3gp` support:

  ```
  <source src='video.3gp' type='video/3gpp; codecs="mp4v.20.8, samr"'>
  ```